# enable ssh user login (Debian)

Tags: debian, ssh

How can I enable ssh for user administrator?
I use this in sshd_config:
AllowUsers administrator
After restart ssh, I tried login, I typed username + pw, but I dont got any answer. Whats wrong?
Maybe this settings are the reasons?

```
Match group filetransfer
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: You can try `ssh -v` to show more messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`m using this sshd_config to allow root and Users in sshlogin, to login via ssh.
Users in group netlogin are chrooted:

```
# 2009-04-27
AllowGroups root netlogin sshlogin
PermitRootLogin without-password
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

#AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
AddressFamily inet
HostbasedAuthentication no
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
IgnoreRhosts yes
MaxStartups 4
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
LoginGraceTime 60
LogLevel INFO
PrintLastLog yes
PrintMotd no
Protocol 2
Port 22
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
RSAAuthentication yes
ServerKeyBits 768
StrictModes yes
SyslogFacility AUTH
TCPKeepAlive yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11Forwarding no

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group netlogin
    ChrootDirectory /home
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```